# web3js getPastLogs function returns error: query returned more than 10000 results

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, logs, filters

I have a local ethereum node and I am trying to filter an event for a contract address between a range of blocks. However it throws the following error:

```
node:15689) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: query returned more than 10000 results
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/mnt/ssd/abi_extraction/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:16)
    at /mnt/ssd/abi_extraction/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:170:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/mnt/ssd/abi_extraction/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:111:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/mnt/ssd/abi_extraction/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/mnt/ssd/abi_extraction/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/mnt/ssd/abi_extraction/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/mnt/ssd/abi_extraction/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:15689) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15689) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This was when my toBlock was 9095563 and fromBlock was 8945008. Even when I reduced the block range by a mere 10 blocks, it was returning the same error. My code is below:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let infura_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/853346f695b740fe8bd7d8f583bcf55f"
let web3 = Web3(Web3.IPCProvider("./../.ethereum/geth.ipc"))

const params = {
    address: "0x0e3a2a1f2146d86a604adc220b4967a898d7fe07",
    topics: ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"],
    fromBlock: 8945008,
    toBlock: 9095563  
};

web3.eth.getPastLogs(params).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Is there a way to bypass this so that I can get more than 10000 results:

1. For 10 block difference issue
2. For the range mentioned in the code.

Comment: How exactly is the range [8945008, 9095563] "a mere 10 blocks"???

Comment: I said that it returns same error for both ranges when the difference is 10 blocks or when the difference is that as shown above

Comment: Well, I tried from 8945008 to 8945018, and I did not encounter the problem that you're mentioning. Perhaps you'd care to be a little more specific and state exactly which range of 10 blocks is giving you this error.

Comment: Im trying to execute the same code on two system. One system fetches the logs for a maximum difference of 60 block i.e. when my toBlock is 8945068. But the same code on an another system which also has a local ethereum node doesn't even run for toBlock = 8945018

Comment: That doesn't quite sound like the original problem posted. Do you have a range of 10 blocks for which you get "`query returned more than 10000 results`" or not?

Comment: Yes I do. But I also want to bypass this error to get more than 10000 results

Comment: `Yes I do` - please share that range.

Comment: `But I also want to bypass this error to get more than 10000 results` - that's not a problem, simply use a smaller range.

Comment: Desired range : toBlock 8945008 and fromBlock 9095563 . However if there is no possible way to establish this what might be causing the 10 block difference to throw this error?

Comment: That's not a range of 10 blocks!!! Please share a range of 10 blocks for which you get the aforementioned error.

Comment: The 10 block range is the same as you tried yourself and was running successfully for you but not for me. I.e when toBlock is 8945018

Comment: NP, I provided a general solution (which I've been using myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Apparently the issue was with the IPC provider. I changed it to HttpProvider(path_to_local_node) and now it is working flawlessly on the ethereum node and returning logs as desired. I am posting the updated code:

```
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(nodeURL));

const params = {
    address: "0x0e3a2a1f2146d86a604adc220b4967a898d7fe07",
    topics: ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"],
    fromBlock: 8945008,
    toBlock: 8945078
};

web3.eth.getPastLogs(params).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem using *Divide & Conquer* strategy:

```
async function getPastLogs(web3, address, topics, fromBlock, toBlock) {
    if (fromBlock <= toBlock) {
        try {
            return await web3.eth.getPastLogs({address, topics, fromBlock, toBlock});
        }
        catch (error) {
            const midBlock = (fromBlock + toBlock) >> 1;
            const arr1 = await getPastLogs(web3, address, topics, fromBlock, midBlock);
            const arr2 = await getPastLogs(web3, address, topics, midBlock + 1, toBlock);
            return [...arr1, ...arr2];
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that if `web3.eth.getPastLogs` throws an error even for a single block (for example, as a result of network disconnection), then it will be stuck in infinite recursion, and the process will ultimately exit due to stack overflow.